# How to correctly connect mysql docker container with go ?

Tags: go, docker

I started to learn docker today and have big blocker. 
What I am trying to do is thatopen mysql connection using go-sql-driver/mysql.

I can connect mysql container using sequel pro with localhost:3306
However, it seems not working with go-sql-driver/mysql

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:welcome@/tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")
```

//tried 172.17.0.1:3306 and 172.17.0.2:3306

and this is my container's network info

```
"Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "47b2a5c798522f5eb6688c4540b4017335eb174528d510b9f1d35d125313017c",
                "EndpointID": "ca2256684928e4184efd36f880cd70d3809d79db5b30c10ab37c66ccbbbba610",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
            }
        }
```

I am not sure which info I should provide to get right answer since I am new to vm

Comment: If know you can connect to the database at `127.0.0.1:3306`, why not try that address?

Comment: I already tried with localhost:3306       db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:welcome@/tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")

Comment: If "sequel pro" can connect to `localhost:3306`, there's no reason the Go driver shouldn't be able to. What is the difference between the 2 processes?

Comment: That is why I posted question ... it should work but its not

Comment: What is the error from Go? How are you running "sequel pro" so that it will connect? What is the port published for the container?

Comment: Can you confirm that:
MySQL is running in a docker container
"sql pro" is running on your dockerhost 

Where are you trying to connect from with go? Another docker container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your connection is wrong, use

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:welcome@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")
```

Notice that "/" is removed after "@"

The README says a valid connection path is like

```
[username[:password]@][protocol[(address)]]/dbname
```